# Hibernate : alias getting automatically updated ( javax.persistence.criteria.Selection.alias(String name))

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, jpa

My Table  Name : PO_details  :- Root<PO_details>

Column Name

1. PO_number
2. PO_discr
3. PO_customer

Please find below = Hibernate/ JPA

```
 Expression Po_1 = PO_details.get(PO_number);
    Po_1.alias("SELECT");
    
    Expression Po_2 = PO_details.get(PO_number);
    Po_2.alias("GROUP");
    
    criteriaQuery.multiselect(Po_1 );
    criteriaQuery.groupBy(Po_2);
```

**Error**
Multi-select expressions defined duplicate alias : **GROUP**

**Observation :**
Somehow Po_1 alias is getting updated with Po_2 alias .

I need both Po_1 (SELECT) and Po_2(GROUP) in the query with their respected alias

Please help me

Comment: I have seen similar odd behaviour two years ago and I do believe that is hibernate bug: https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-14441. Workaround: use JPQL instead of criteria api.

Comment: Thank you , can you let me know if in  any hibernate version this issue is been resolved

Comment: I need to add alias